# 302 redirect, get "redirected from" URL

Tags: redirect, http-referer, http-status-code-302

Is there any way to identify the url which redirected to another one?

To be clear, let's say we have `example-domain.com` which redirects (302) to `exampledomain.com`.

I thought that maybe the http_referer server variable would contain the redirecting url but thats not the case. Is that possible at all?

Comment: Based on the title, i was thinking "http_referer?", and was suprised to see the last part of your question. Upvoting as this question got me curious.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't let me comment or upvote as I'm too new. Wondering if you're still having this problem - as I am too.

If you have control over both domain names, I would suggest you 302 to the URL exampledomain.com?refUrl=example-domain.com and pull the data from the querystring.

If you DON'T have control over both domain names, you are in same situation as me and my non-intentional duplicate question ([3rd party is 302 redirect to my website, how to stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057172/3rd-party-is-302-redirect-to-my-website-how-to-stop))

In my case from testing, the http_referrer returns the site 'before' the site doing the 302. IE "Google (Click) Example-Domain (302) ExampleDomain"... the http referrer returns Google.

Comment: no, no progress on this issue... we just ignored it at my company! :D