# 3rd party is 302 redirect to my website, how to stop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http-status-code-302

EDIT:

Maybe a better tl;dr version of my question (my brain is a little mashed)...

Either (ideally): Can I detect a referral URL with an off-domain 302 redirect?
Or: Can I detect that a 302 redirect was used to access my website?

EDIT 2 (from suggestion):

Request.UrlReferrer doesn't work in this situation, it returns as simply "https://www.google.co.uk/". I was expecting perhaps the referring URL of www.google.co.uk?url=maliciouswebsite.com - but sadly not.

---

A malicious website appears in Google. The link in Google points to www.maliciouswebsite.com - however when you click the link, you get sent to www.mywebsite.com.

So people google "MaliciousWebsite" and find their way to MyWebsite. I did a DNS check on maliciouswebsite.com and it has been 302 Redirected to mywebsite.com.

What I'm trying to do is "If the request is a 302 redirect sent from MaliciousWebsite.com - do not show my website".

I need a way of identifying that the request originated from MaliciousWebsite in some way.

Hope that makes sense!?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ASP.NET since you tagged the question as C#.

Well, ASP.NET offers a property that give you the address of the page where the request to your page originated from.

Try to use

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, Request.UrlReferrer doesn't work in this situation, it returns as simply "https://www.google.co.uk/". I was expecting perhaps the referring URL of www.google.co.uk?url=maliciouswebsite.com - but sadly not.